# figure in tax into the equation

Tags: javascript

Okay So I am trying to add tax into this equation if the dropdown for tax is selected as `1 or Yes` My code below is what I have:

```
function Calculate() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
    var price = $(par).find('input#price').val();
    var tax = $(par).find('#tax').val();
    if(price == ''){
        return false;
    }
    var qty = $(this).val();
    if(qty == ''){
        return false;
    }
    if(tax == '1'){
        var tax = "<?php echo $this->config->item('default_tax'); ?>";
    }
    else{
        var tax = '0.00';
    }
    var total = parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(tax) * parseFloat(qty);
    $(par).find('input#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
    $(par).find('#Ltotal').text(total.toFixed(2));
    CalculateTotal();
}
```

Before I added all the tax stuff, it was working just fine. But I need that tax figured in unfortunately.

Now when the above code runs I get the amount of tax on each product and not the total amount.

So for example if I have a tax rate as: `8.650%`

And a line total of: `$15.00`

and a quantity of: `1`

The script would return `1.30` for the amount. Which is the tax amount. The total should be `16.30`

What am I doing wrong?

I'm going to say something is wrong with this line:

```
var total = parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(tax) * parseFloat(qty);
```

But not sure what.

Comment: Your tax needs to be written as 1.0865, using you example of 8.65% above, and it isn't clear from your code if this is the case. Also, what does CalculateTotal() do. All your variables are declared with var, so are local to the Calculate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct equation would be price * qty, then multiple times 1 + tax rate.

```
var total = (parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty)) * (1+parseFloat(tax));
```

You have to be careful though because javascript uses floats and this can cause some strange (unexact) measurements.